# PHP update url in variable

Tags: php, string

```
$link = http://site.com/view/page.php?id=50&reviews=show
```

How can we add `&extra=video` after `id=50`?

- `id` is always numeric.
- url can have many other variables after `?id=50`
- `&extra=video` should be added before the first `&` and after the `50` (value of `id`)

It will be used this way:

```
echo '<a href="' . $link . '">Get video</a>';
```

Thanks.

Comment: Why is the position in the string so important? It is still going to get interpreted as a query string attribute regardless of its position. Would obviously be easier just to append it to the url.

Comment: You just asked this a few minutes ago. There was a good answer then, what's different now?

Comment: @Scott Saunders question is deleted, that solution doesn't work.

Comment: `$link .= '&extra=video';` unless you can justify your constraint on needing to explicitly position '&extra=video' in the middle of the query string

Comment: @Treffynnon I have updated this question. In fact the url is very long and I don't know exactly how it ends. There is used post method in the form, which gives many many post variables. Just want this code to be added and work properly, seems adding variable after id=50 is quite not bas solution, I will see it and know that everything is ok.

Comment: @meagar will it work if $link gives something like "http://site.com/view/?id=50&reviews=show&other=variable//#" ?

Comment: @Ignatz Yes, but you'll have `$_GET['other'] == 'variable//'`.  Where is the `'//#'` coming from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is ID always the first post parameter? If so, then you could jsut do some sort of string manipulation. Use `strpos($link, "&")` to find out the position where you want to insert. Then do a few `substr()` based on that position and then append them all together. Its kind of hacky I know, but it will definitely work.

```
$pos = strpos($link, "&");
$first  = substr($link, 0, $pos);
$last = substr($link, $pos);
$extra = "&extra=video";
$newLink = $first . $extra . $last;
```

See this link for some of the string manipulation functions that I mentioned above: https://www.php.net/strings

Comment: using string functions for url parsing might produce unexpected results(specifically invalid urls) for different urls...

Comment: I agree. Thus why I asked if it was the first post parameter and said it was a hacky solution. I'm not proud of it but its early...

Answer (score 2):

As Treffynnon says, the order seldomly matters. However, if you *really* need if for some reason, just use

- `parse_url` to get the querystring
- `parse_str` to create an array of parameter
- `array_splice` to inject a parameter
- `http_build_query` to rebuild a proper query string

Answer (score 2):

This will do it for you

```
<?php 
    $linkArray = explode('&',$link);
    $linkArray[0] += '&extra=video';
    $link = implode('&',$linkArray);
?>
```

1. Explode will split the link string at every &, so it doesn't care how many elements you have in the url.
2. The first element, will be everything including the id=## before the first & sign. So we append whatever you want to appear after it.
3. We put our array together again as a string, separating each element by an &.

Answer (score 1):

i would suggest to use functions specifically aimed at url parsing, not general string functions:

```
$link = 'http://site.com/view/?id=50&reviews=show';
$query = array();
parse_str(parse_url($link, PHP_URL_QUERY), $query);
$query['extra'] = 'video';
$linkNew = http_build_url($link, array('query' => http_build_query($query)));
```

Comment: I really like `http_build_url`, but it should be mentioned the pecl HTTP extension is not included by default.